# Vue Is there a pseudo 3D swiper or carousel component in any UI library that meets my description?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, carousel, swiper.js

I'm sorry for asking a simple question about the component library, but my requirement is very specific. I have searched through many UI and swiper libraries, but I haven't found this kind of component yet: an image in the center with two sidewise images under it (of z-index), slightly overlapping the image in the center. The two images are "prev" and "next", and play in a loop.

I expect the component to look something like this:

```
   +-------+
+--|       |--+
| 0|   1   |2 |
+--|       |--+
   +-------+
     . . .
```

I've found a library called [vue-carousel-3d](https://github.com/wlada/vue-carousel-3d), But its style is that sidewise images have a slanted angle, and I don't want this slanted angle. I want all three images should be perfectly square.